# Blender NPR: flat shader that shows depth?

Tags: rendering

What process could be used to create a 2d image from blender that shows depth?

For Example:
[image: Fol Amor]

Should a flat shader be modified to also show depth? Or is a flat shader combined with something like a depth pass to create this look? What would be the best way of making something with this effect?

Comment: Toon shading i guess. That's about it.

Comment: I dont see any depth in this picture, there is no dof, no distance mist, no depth de-saturation or no shape shading. There is nothing that cant be build-in into textures and using toon shaders.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty subtle on here, you can see it on the arms of the male character.

Comment: I guess you want a normal shading combined with toon shading. The factor between the two decides how subtle the effect is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fol Amor's toon shading was a combination of:

Self-luminated material (the flat-looking character)
Shadow pass (maya has ramp shaders, don't know about blender)
Rim pass (shader that highlights white around character)
zdepth as mentioned above.

it also has to do with how you composite all those passes together. You can do so via Adobe After Effects.

If you dig around vimeo, some of their artist have a making of that's specifically towards their render passes.

Their film's environment was a combination of 3d props/visuals with 2d matte paintings for the background.

Cheers!